# Как сделать бесконечный цикл рандомизации на bash

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

Как сделать на bash чтобы генерировалось бесконечно для вывода в трубу `openssl rand 20 -base64` ? спасибо

```
while true; do openssl rand 20 -base64; done;
```

правильно?
генерится, но как мне это засунуть в трубу правильно - передать на вход другой проге?

```
while true; do openssl rand 20 -base64; done | programm2
```

`programm2` стала сильно тормозить, стала обрабатывать пакетами по 4096 строк, далее делает паузу и опять продолжает так же... `programm2` с другими генераторами и в других вариациях так не лагала никогда, скорость всегда высокая.
в подобной вариации например `keys=100000; openssl rand $[32*keys] -base64 | programm2` все работает отлично и с высокой скоростью. Нужна бесконечная генерация с рандомизацией по трубе без сохранения входа для `pipe` в файл.
`programm2` скомпилирована из исходников с github и написана вроде на Си, принимает по трубе начиная от cat text | до любых генераторов типа crunch, maskprocessor, etc. Но `while true; do ...; done;` принимать не хочет нормально никак, я уже и fifo пробовал и пропускать строки через awk, во всяком случае в вышеуказанном синтаксисе. 
Может подскажите как сделать цикл другими средствами? Или какой-то другой генератор рандомный посоветуете.
Как будет выглядеть аналог `while true; do openssl rand 20 -base64; done;` но с `for(;;)` ?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает предложенный вариант?

Comment: `while true; do openssl rand 20 -base64; done | programm2`
а почему бы не так?

Comment: не знаю почему, но скорость обработки `programm2` упала жутко, раз в 50 от обычного... Слышал, что есть еще вариант сделать процесс бесконечным через `for( ; ; );` . Может кто подскажет как тут будет синтаксис в примере правильно?

Comment: почему-то `programm2` стала обрабатывать пакетами по 4096 строк, далее делает паузу и опять продолжает так же... `programm2` с другими генераторами и в других вариациях так не лагала никогда, скорость всегда высокая... может со стороны ``openssl` какие заковыки идут? может есть какой-то иной синтаксис у `while`, чтобы передать в трубу по-иному как-то?

Comment: Добавте выдержки из комментариев прямо в вопрос. Заодно - "programm2 с другими генераторами и в других вариациях так не лагала никогда" - было бы не плохо также пример с другими генераторами и с высокой скоростью.

Answer (score 1):

Буфера тут не причем. Система тормозит, и медленно генерируются байты, потому что в случае с:

```
while true; do openssl rand 20 -base64; done
```

вы в бесконечном цикле запускаете много раз процесс openssl, который генерирует всего 20 байт за раз. Однако запуск процесса - операция достаточно дорогостоящая для операционной системы. Тем более - openssl. Тем самым, вы ощутимо грузите систему. Вы заставляете её все время запускать новые процессы (которые быстро отрабатывают своё).

В случае с:

```
keys=100000; openssl rand $[32*keys] -base64
```

всего один запуск процесса. Он не сильно грузит систему.

Возможно, вам стоит пересмотреть условия задачи. Не генерировать по 20 байт за один запуск процесса openssl.

Т.е. вам необходимо сократить количество запусков процессов: не 1000 раз запустить openssl для генерации по 20 байт, а, например, 10 раз запустить, но с генерацией 2000 байт.
Итого, количество рэндомных байт будет одинаковое, а нагрузка на систему намного меньше. Это снизит нагрузку на систему, и увеличит скорость генерации.

В идеале, запускать процесс один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего накапливается буффер.
Надо включить построчную буферезауцию перед `openssl`:

```
while true; do **stdbuf --output=L --error=L**  openssl rand 20 -base64; done |programm2
```

Comment: Ммм.. `**stdbuf: command not found`

Comment: без звездочек. они для выделения синтаксиса на сайте )

Comment: спасибо за помощь. но нет, не помогает тоже... подозреваю, что проблема в каких-то permission или еще в чем-то секьюрном со стороны openssl. моей квалификации чайника не хватает понять)

Answer (score 0):

`sleep 1` в цикл поставь. Иначе у тебя так и будет виснуть. Слишком быстро выполняется операция, ее повтор без задержки в цикле сильно грузит систему.